# Errors in math line when I use Beamer with pdf viewer error Doc[Open("%bm.pdf")][Fileopen(

Tags: beamer, pdftex, errors, acrobat

See the code (for a presentation):
When I only skip the math symbol $\overrightarrow$ then everything is fine and the pdf output file is generated without errors. This code works fine also when I change documentclass **beamer** into **article**. I use Miktex (Windows 11) and Acrobat reader DC as viewer (version 2012.007.20091). The error is always ''There was an error during opening of the file''. Then comes the message [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")].
I checked the parameters in Define output files:

```
    - Path to (La)tex compiler: C:\program files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe (place of file confirmed to be correct)
    - Server: AcroviewA21 (3 x).
```

I deleted Acrobat completely and re-installed Acrobat reader again. But the problem remains. What else can I do ?

I made a minimal but complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Mass and Energy}
\begin{itemize}
\item m:=(rest)mass
\item Momentum $\rightarrow$ vector w.r.t. an observer
\item Momentum $\overrightarrow{P}$ vector w.r.t. an observer.  % this line is the problem!
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit (22-12-2021): Thanks for your reply. But also $\vec{p]$ does not work. Moreover, even a simple letter $a$ results in the same error. This is irrespective of using in-line math or equations. Surprisingly, things like $\alpha$, $\beta^{\frac{1}{2}}$, \sin{\alpha}$ all works fine, but not $\sin(a)$. This is really driving me nuts !!!

Comment: Instead of `$\overrightarrow{P}$` try to use `$\vec{P}$`. I use `sumatra` for viewer and haven't ay problems with compilation of your code.

Comment: Is using sumatra the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment ...

You have some problem not related to LaTeX. Your MWE, extended with your edit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Mass and Energy}
\begin{itemize}
\item m:=(rest)mass
\item Momentum $\rightarrow$ vector w.r.t. an observer
\item Momentum $\overrightarrow{P}$ vector w.r.t. an observer.  % this line is the problem!
\end{itemize}

$\alpha$, $\beta^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $\sin{\alpha}$ and also $\sin(a)$ works fine!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works fine. Result in Adobe Acrobat DC is:

[image]

I compile with recent MikTeX installed in windows 10. I don't know (and also doubt) if windows 11 have some problem with Adobe Acrobat
DC (64 bit). For editor I use WinEdt 10.3 (where for ˙PDF Viewer  I have set `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"`.

Your problems are not caused by LaTeX rather your installation of dobe Acrobat DC. You may try to reinstall it (after uninstalling existing using utility which should be part of your Acrobat installation. In its installation I use default settings provided by Adobe.).

Comment: Problem solved (finally)! It turns out that I had to update some packages in Miktex. Then after Refresh database filenames the problem was solved. Thanks for your help.